# UITapGestureRecognizer not (always) working for targets that are different than UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom iOS controller class that adds a `UIButton` programatically to a given `UIView`. The button has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` associated to it but it works only when the custom controller is a `@property` of the `UIViewController` that embeds the view and button.

See https://github.com/vasile/ios-gesture-recognizer/ with 2 button examples, the 1st one doesn't record the tap gestures.

[image: XCode project example]

Can someone explain why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about object lifetimes. In order to be the target of the button when it is tapped, the target object must *exist* at the time the button is tapped.

That's not true for the first button (Nothing Will Happen), because the target is just a local variable that immediately goes out of existence. The other target objects, on the other hand, are persistent. A property of a view controller instance, for example, persists as long as the view controller does. And a view controller is usually very long-lived; in particular, if properly used, it lives as long as the button does if the button is a subview of the view controller's own view!

Comment: Thanks matt, it makes sense "the target object must exist", Apple should add it to the official documentation because the target definition `An object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the receiver when it recognizes a gesture` is too vague.

Comment: I don't think Apple is to be faulted for not mentioning explicitly that an object that doesn't exist can't do any work. That's kind of obvious. As I said, it's really about object lifetimes. That's the piece of the puzzle you seem not to have understood (i.e. the thing that prompted your question). But it is _key_ to understand object lifetimes if you're going to do object-oriented programming! Your question brings out just how crucial it is.